# Can't connect to SQL server through external connection, but connects fine through internal connection

Tags: php, sql-server

On an internal connection on the same network as the SQL server I am able to connect OK, using the following connection string:

```
$servername = "1.1.1.1\namedinstance";
$loguser = "user";
$logpassword = "password";
$database = "dbname";

$odbc="odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$servername;Database=$database;";
$db = new PDO( $odbc , $loguser, $logpassword);
```

However, from an external server I get the following error message:

*"Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired in..."*

I am also able to connect externally to our old SQL server, the only difference between that connection string and the new one above is the addition of the named instance (the previous working version only connects through IP address).

Any ideas why I can't connect externally?

Comment: Look in the SQL ERRORLOG to see if there's any more information about the error.  And verify that you have UDP connection to port 1343 and TCP to whatever port that named instance is actually listening on.  Could simply be a firewall issue.  You may need to reconfigure the named instance to listen on a fixed port and configure that in your firewall.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ok, so it's likely a sql / port 
 / firewall configuration issue? I'll ask our sysadmin guy to review the settings. thx for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Allow TCP port 1433 on your external firewall, you need to **contact firewall team**.

**Source:** your application server IP.
**Destination:** your SQL Server IP.
**Port:** 1433 (if you have not changed the default port, if changed then ask firewall team to allow that port)